# How to take the Dynamic-table cell value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This is a table of one of my jsp page. I want to take the selected value of the column empId for a javascript method.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Casual Leave Balance</th>
            <th>Annual Leave Balance</th>
            <th>Sick Leave Balance</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="leavebalances" items="${LeaveAllBalanceList}">
            <tr>
                <td><dev class="correct" name="empId" onclick="selectempId(this)"> ${leavebalances.empId}</dev></td>
                <td>${leavebalances.empId}</td>
                <td>${leavebalances.casual}</td>
                <td>${leavebalances.annual}</td>
                <td>${leavebalances.sick}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>                            
</table>
```

my javascript code segment

```
function selectempId(emp){
    alert(emp);   
}
```

But It (onclick) doesn't work. There are only methods to get selected values of dynamic dropdowns. Please tell me how to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: `onclick()="selectempId(this)"` what is with the `()` ? Is that proper?

Comment: @epascarello  no no, It should be corrected as onclick="selectempId(this)". thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, my problem was being unable to pass td's values to javascript function, because there were no unique id's assigned for required td tags (dynamic table). So I gave dynamic ids.

```
<c:forEach var="leavebalances" items="${LeaveAllBalanceList}">
        <tr>
                <td id ="${leavebalances.empId}" class="correct" name="empId" onclick="selectEmpId(this.id)">${leavebalances.empId}</td>
                <td>${leavebalances.empId}</td>                 
                <td>${leavebalances.casual}</td>
                <td>${leavebalances.annual}</td>
                <td>${leavebalances.sick}</td>
        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

/////////////////////javascript function///////////////////////////////

```
function selectEmpId(val) {
        alert(val);        
}
```

Comment: What is difference between my answer and yours& ))

Comment: I found this answer with the help of your answer. I couldn't execute js code until there is no id in td tag. that's why I use your method to generate unique id's. Thanks alot. :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<dev class="correct" name="empId" onclick="selectempId(this)"> ${leavebalances.empId}</dev>
```

You don't need `()`

Comment: Yeah. I had made that mistake in publishing. but still I can't use its value in javascript. Then the problem must be in the javascript code. No? empId must be String. but here javascript method have to have a parameter type like dev or something??

now I have attached javascript code segement as well

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value to javascript. But I don't know the `dev` tag in html. I think it is `div`.

```
<td><div class="correct" name="empId" onclick="selectempId(${leavebalances.empId})"> ${leavebalances.empId}</div></td>
```

Or you can pass to `td`'s `onclick` action.

```
<td onclick="selectempId(${leavebalances.empId})">${leavebalances.empId}</td>
```

Comment: Are you sure empId is not null? I think my code is correct

Comment: thanks @Afusn It should be div.
Then I used your div method. But Javascript code doesn't work. It works only with noparameter call. 
<td onclick="selectempId()"> and js has no para function. why? 

Is there a problem with parameters?? 
selectempId(${leavebalances.empId}) , function selectempId(emp){}

Comment: What would come when inspect element inside method?

Comment: js function doesn't executes.. no alerts.

Comment: Is empId displayed as table td?

Comment: yeah. that's the td, I click.